# How to detect the button in dialog "Open this page in appName" has been clicked

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

I'm embedding a `react.js` website in my app.
I use deep link, so in iPhone, the dialog would pop up and show '**Open this page in appName**'.

I want my website is blank until the user click the dialog button whether `cancel` or `open`.

Is there any event I can listen to?Or any other way to achieve this?